# Colors are not filling in certain places

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am utilizing turtle to make a xmastree. The task is to color the individual pieces. The "trunk" portion of code works and will fill correctly. The Layer1(), Layer2(), and Layer3() do not fill with color as they should. Any help would be appreciated.

I have looked through the other problems on stack overflow. I have repositioned my variables. Still, nothing.

""" Lab 9 Exercise 3
Author: Jonathan Wheatley

Define a function drawXmasTree(t, blc, scale = 1) You may add further parameters beyond the first three if you wish (note: give any additional parameters default values!). Your
tree should resemble three filed, superimposed green triangles (containing colored ball ornamets) over a brown trunk.
blc and scale should work as in the preceding exercise. Show results at two different scales.

"""

```
from turtle import Turtle
scale = 1.25

def drawXmasTree():
    a = trunk()
    b = Layer1()
    c = Layer2()
    d = Layer3()

def trunk():
    t = Turtle()
    t.pencolor("brown")
    t.fillcolor("brown")
    t.shape("turtle")
    t.up()
    t.goto((scale * -100), (scale * -100))
    t.down()
    for count in range(2):
        t.begin_fill()
        t.forward(scale * 10)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(scale *100)
        t.left(90)
        t.end_fill()
    t.hideturtle()

def Layer1():
    t = Turtle()
    t.pencolor("green")
    t.fillcolor("green")
    t.shape("turtle")
    t.up()
    t.goto((scale * -150), 0)
    t.down()
    for count in range(3):
        t.begin_fill()
        t.forward(scale * 110)
        t. left(120)
        t.end_fill()
    t.hideturtle()

def Layer2():
    t = Turtle()
    t.pencolor("green")
    t.fillcolor("green")
    t.shape("turtle")
    t.up()
    t.goto((scale * -147), 15)
    t.down()
    for count in range(3):
        t.begin_fill()
        t.forward(scale * 104)
        t.left(120)
        t.end_fill()
    t.hideturtle()

def Layer3():
    t = Turtle()
    t.fillcolor("green")
    t.pencolor("green")
    t.shape("turtle")
    t.up()
    t.goto((scale * -145), 30)
    t.down()
    for count in range(3):
        t.begin_fill()
        t.forward(scale * 100)
        t.left(120)
        t.end_fill()
    t.hideturtle()

def main():
    u = drawXmasTree()
main()
```

When the code is run the turtle should display, draw in the correct colored line, and then the shape should fill.

Answer (score 0):

So, in running so more tests, I seem to be getting positive results by breaking the begin_fill() and end_fill out of the for loop. I don't know why this was working in the Trunk() section but it does not work in the subsequent sections.

Please, if you find a way to make this code better let me know. I would love to learn something and improve my coding.

Thank you.